# mount not working for utf-8

Tags: high-sierra, mount, internationalization, utf-8

I've set the locale:

```
$locale
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

However, while this mount works:

```
$ mount -t smbfs "//Mercury/Echo" "/Volumes/Echo"
Password for Mercury:
```

This mount fails:

```
$ mount -t smbfs "//Προκρούστης/DiningRoom" "/Volumes/DiningRoom"
mount_smbfs: URL parsing failed, please correct the URL and try again: Invalid argument
```

Any suggestions as to how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[URL-encode](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) the server name:

```
Προκρούστης > %CE%A0%CF%81%CE%BF%CE%BA%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%8D%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%82
```

The quotes aren't required here, so the following should work:

```
mount -t smbfs //%CE%A0%CF%81%CE%BF%CE%BA%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%8D%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%82/DiningRoom /Volumes/DiningRoom
```